# what does print(s%%s) mean here?

Tags: python

```
s='s=%r;print(s%%s)';print(s%s)
```

I understand % is to replace something in a string by s (but actually who to replace?)
Maybe more intriguing is, why the `print(s%%s)` become `print(s%s)` automatically after `%s` is replaced by `s` itself?

Comment: i changed the problem so now it asks about %%s

Comment: `%%` is how you write a literal `%` in a format string.

Comment: no. if i let a="print(s%%s)"

Comment: Consider `"%s%%s" % 'follow me '` => `'follow me %s'`.

Comment: Ok i got it. %% only reduced to % when you actually use % for this string...........

Comment: but it will not happen if you do not use replacement.   btw who invented % as replacement. is this Python unique? or C also use it?

Comment: C has it in the format strings passed to `printf`. Although some of the letters are used differently.

Comment: but not with string%something, it is % inside string, and something as arguments to printf right?

Comment: bozeng is asking about % the (Python) ***format operator***, as in `formatstring % formatitems`, not the use of % inside the format-string fields: "%s %5.2f"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"%%"` you see in that code is a "conversion specifier" for the older [printf-style of string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Most conversion specifiers tell Python how to convert an argument that is passed into the `%` format operator (for instance, `"%d"` says to convert the next argument to a decimal integer before inserting it into the string).

`"%%"` is different, because it directly converts to a single `"%"` character without consuming an argument. This conversion is needed in the format string specification, since otherwise any `"%"` would be taken as the first part of some other code and there would be no easy way to produce a string containing a percent sign.

The code you show is a quine (a program that produces its own code as its output). When it runs `print(s%s)`, it does a string formatting operation where both the format string, and the single argument are the same string, `s`.

The `"%r"` in the string is a conversion specifier that does a `repr` of its argument. `repr` on a string produces the string with quotes around it. This is where the quoted string comes from in the output.

The `"%%"` produces the `%` operator that appears between the two `s`'s in the `print` call. If only one `"%"` was included in `s`, you'd get an error about the formatting operation expecting a second argument (since `%s` is another conversion specifier).

Comment: I agree with you. But to note if you use "%%" directly, and print it , it is a double percent. E.g: print("%%") and see the output

Comment: It means its behavior is not consistent cross at least print and print with format

Comment: Your right, that by itself,  `"%%"` is just a string with two percent signs in it. It's only when you use that as a format string that the two characters turn into one. Try `"%%" % ()`, to format the string with no arguments and you'll see it happen.

Answer (score 2):

```
print '% %s' % '' #wrong
print '%% %s' % '' #correct and print '% '
```

Think about \\ and \.

Comment: No I am using Python 3

Comment: My point is about double %. As more above academic answers had mentioned, any string need to be persentaged mustn't contain a single %. JUST use double % instead.